# if server not sending Response Cache headers "cache-control" how to cache the response in Android App

Tags: android, caching

I need to implement a caching for my android application, Server Response Contains TTL value which represents when to fetch the data again. Currently, i'm Using Retofit to get the Server Response and OKHTTP3. This is my server JSON Response, Can someone link me to any third party library or any guide to implementing  this is in Android

```
{
"ttl": 5,
"status": "ok",
"source": "techcrunch",
"sortBy": "top",
-"articles": [
-{
"author": "Romain Dillet",
"title": "Apple just released iOS 11 developer beta 5",
"description": "Apple just dropped a brand new beta for your favorite iOS update of the year. While iOS 11 isn’t coming out until September, the company has been testing..",
"url": "https://techcrunch.com/2017/08/07/apple-just-released-ios-11-developer-beta-5/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/ios-11-preview-5.jpg?w=764&h=400&crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2017-08-07T17:08:08Z"
},
-{
"author": "Megan Rose Dickey",
"title": "Uber discloses details of Travis Kalanick’s deposition in Waymo lawsuit",
"description": "Uber unsealed former CEO Travis Kalanick's deposition in the Uber versus Waymo self-driving car technology case over the weekend. Kalanick, who was deposed..",
"url": "https://techcrunch.com/2017/08/07/uber-discloses-details-of-travis-kalanicks-deposition-in-waymo-lawsuit/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/gettyimages-543263066.jpg?w=764&h=400&crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2017-08-07T16:52:39Z"
},
-{
"author": "Jordan Crook",
"title": "The battle between hotels and Airbnb escalates in NYC",
"description": "The war between Airbnb and the hotel industry rages on, and it's reaching new lows here in New York. A campaign, backed by the Hotel Association of New York..",
"url": "https://techcrunch.com/2017/08/07/the-battle-between-hotels-and-airbnb-escalates-in-nyc/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/gettyimages-169277082.jpg?w=764&h=400&crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2017-08-07T15:25:29Z"
},
-{
"author": "Romain Dillet",
"title": "iPhone 8 could scan your face even if your phone is on a table",
"description": "Apple’s HomePod firmware is the gift that keeps on giving. When the company shared an early build of the speaker firmware, many developers started digging..",
"url": "https://techcrunch.com/2017/08/07/iphone-8-could-scan-your-face-even-if-your-phone-is-on-a-table/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/2016-iphone-7-gettyimages-599948224.jpg?w=764&h=400&crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2017-08-07T14:02:43Z"
}
]
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#response-caching

Comment: How can i use the Server JSON Response TTL value to configure the cache

Comment: I would recommend that you fix the server to use HTTP cache headers appropriately.

Comment: I've no access to Server Code and IOS team already implement their own Cache Manager to handle this, Unfortunately, I  have to find a way to implement the same in Android

Comment: Then you'll have to implement your own cache (e.g., using `LRUCache`) and your own timeout mechanism.